# Секреты модерации: как вы модерируете сообщество?

Tags: обсуждение, faq, модерация

С первого дня существования Stack Overflow в него была заложена идея, что сайтом и сообществом должны управлять сами участники. Для того, чтобы достичь этой цели, были добавлены инструменты модерации, которые становятся доступны участнику с ростом его репутации. В пределе, любой участники может получить практически те же привилегии, что и модератор.

Инструменты модерации – это только полдела. Вторая половина – это их правильное и своевременное использование. Как можно видеть из истории правок, многие участники не только постоянно улучшают содержимое, но и обучают новичков сообщества правилам использования сайта.

Если вы вносите улучшающие правки, участвуете в очередях проверки или у вас есть своя личная стратегия модерации сайта, пожалуйста, поделитесь ей с сообществом! Как мне кажется, многим будут интересны различные подходы к модерации и цели, которые вы пытаетесь достичь!

Answer (score 16):

#### Цель: обучение новых участников правилам сайта

Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы подсказать участникам, которые публикуют слабые сообщения, либо используют сайт неверно, лучшие практики работы с сайтом. Для этого необходимо предоставлять своевременный конструктивный отзыв о недостатках опубликованного сообщения участнику (или неверном использовании сайта) как можно быстрее. Для публикации рекомендаций в виде комментария достаточно иметь привилегию «[оставлять комментарии к чужим сообщениям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)».

**Пример**

1. Используя встроенный поиск применить фильтр поиска сообщений с отрицательным рейтингом за выбранный период времени, например, [`score:..-1 created:1d..`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-1+created%3A1d..) (если вы хотите получить только вопросы, необходимо добавить дополнительный фильтр `is:question`).

   Предположительно, сообщения, получившие отрицательный рейтинг, могут содержать изъян.
2. Просмотреть поочередно сообщения, и, в случае выявления недостатка, оставить комментарий, описывающий проблемы и пути их исправления.

   Помимо комментария, при необходимости, следует проголосовать против, а также за закрытие или удаление вопроса.

Обучение правилам сайта новых участников – ответственная задача, лежащая в основе идеи коллективного управления сайтом. Без непрерывного обучения новых участников сообщество не может долго просуществовать.

Comment: Мне кажется, было бы очень полезно иметь умеренно компактную, собранную в одном месте и ясно изложенную политику сайта, и настойчиво и четко показывать ее всем новичкам. Это помогло бы и новичкам сориентироваться, какие вопросы и как стоит здесь задавать, а какие и как - не стоит, и более взрослым участникам помогло бы быстрее и более осознанно занять более активную позицию в отношении поддержания качества сайта. Информации в отношении политики немало, но она разбросана по множеству вопросов и ответов, и трудно составить себе четкое представление за разумное время.

Answer (score 6):

#### Цель: предоставить отзыв о первом использовании сайта

Крайне важно предоставлять быстрый отзыв сообщества о сообщениях, особенно в тех случаях, когда автор является новичком. Лучший способ предоставить отзыв:

- Проголосовать за или против.
- В случае вопроса, опубликовать ответ.
- В случае правильного ответа, отметить его принятым.

Для просмотра первых сообщений, необходима [привилегия доступа к очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).
<sub>Рекомендации ниже являются дополнением к самой очереди. Просмотренные сообщения, приведенным ниже способом, не учитываются в вашей статистике проверок.</sub>

1. Переходим в очередь проверок. Выбираем первые сообщения. Далее переходим в раздел «[история](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history)».
2. Просматриваем каждое сообщение и: голосуем за или против; закрываем; публикуем ответы; даем уточняющие комментарии, при необходимости.

   При голосовании стоит помнить, что хорошо поставленный первый вопрос – скорее исключение, чем правило. Если вы видите, пускай не самый лучший, но развернутый, правильно оформленный вопрос, смело голосуйте за!

Чем быстрее сообщество предоставляет отзыв, тем выше последующее вовлечение нового участника.

Comment: _В случае правильного ответа, отметить его принятым._ Вы полагаете правильным решать за кого-то, правилен ли ответ ДЛЯ НЕГО? Особенно с учётом того факта, что порой люди спрашивают одно, имея в виду совсем другое - и это при внешней корректности и благообразности вопроса? ИМХО разумнее подсказать автору, что один из ответов можно и даже очень желательно отметить принятым, если он решает проблему (или хотя бы даёт ясно видимый путь к решению).

Comment: @Akina: никто кроме автора вопроса не может принятым отмечать ответ. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262672/4279

Comment: То есть это предложение - неосуществимо, так надо понимать...

Comment: @Akina Если ответ отмечен верным – это означает, что он помог автору вопроса решить его задачу, это может знать только автор вопроса.

Comment: @Akina, наверняка имелся ввиду ответ на _свой собственный_ вопрос

Comment: Да блин же ж... что там пишется? цитирую: _быстрый отзыв сообщества о сообщениях ... когда автор является новичком_. То есть речь идёт про отзыв **НЕ** от автора вопроса. Значит, третий пункт просто невозможен, ибо его может выполнить только сам автор-новичок. Так что его можно из комментируемого сообщения смело удалить.

Comment: @Akina Имеется в виду, что автором вопроса выступаете вы, опытный участник, а автором правильного ответа является новый участник сообщества (ответ – одно из его первых сообщений на сайте).

Comment: Ух ёёё... вот ни в жисть бы не подумал, что речь идёт о таком событии. Тады всё, отбой тревоги.